# Keystroke in Textbox causing LostFocus or Leave

Tags: vb.net, textbox, lost-focus

I have a textbox that is triggered to become visible and take focus (.select) and allows user to modify text in the textbox.  If the users clicks anywhere else (basically leaving/lostfocus on the textbox, I want the textbox to become visible=false.  This works.  My problem is that after becoming visible - any keystroke in the textbox (even SHIFT) causes the LEAVE or LOSTFOCUS event to trigger.  It perplexes me because I'm entering text - not leaving the control.  Any ideas why a keystroke would cause this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.  Without seeing the code for the textbox events it is hard to guess.

Comment: It's probably a Enter/Focus/Leave sequence mishap. It's also probable that you don't need this, so maybe *focus* on something more useful.

Comment: Don't use both events (leaving/lostfocus). The `Leave` event should do the trick. If it triggers early, it may be a problem related to another sequence. See [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) for the complete focus event sequence.